# Java Runtime Environment on OpenSuse 12.1 - which one to choose?

Tags: linux, java, opensuse, ruby

I'm running OpenSUSE 12.1 and want to use Java Runtime enviroment v. 1.6. They ask for an ssh-key.
Which package should I take: the proprietary or the open source one?

How would you install it? Via the terminal or via Yast?

Answer (score 0):

Which to use has been [debated before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977238/why-should-i-use-the-oracle-jdk-over-the-openjdk-or-vice-versa) - basically, it comes down to the fact that OpenJDK, though backed by Oracle, is a more heavily developed open source project while Oracle's JDK is more stable but is not open source, which prevents its inclusion in a lot of purist distributions like Debian.

To get to the OpenJDK (which actually includes its own JRE), try this:

`su -c "yum install java-1.7.0-openjdk"`

Oracle's Java is a little harder to get to; [this site](https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/java-for-opensuse#TOC-Get-JRE) documents the process fairly well. Because Oracle's Java is not in the repository, however, you don't get automatic updating.

Comment: hi there many thanks for the information. Great help. i try to follow all the advices and come back again  and report all the findings. greetings